# Communication Windows Service / Web Server

Tags: c#

We have a current application that has consists of two solutions:

- Windows Service

This one takes care of communication between devices (ie. IoT, and other devices through different communication protocols); this service also contains some logic and runs 24/7; writes ocassionally to a database (SQL or Influx).

- Web Interface

The web interface shows some of the database information; but can also get information from the Windows Service (live data); we currently use RabbitMQ with RPC for this; but it is far from ideal. We use Typescript to call back to a controller; from the controller we RPC to the Windows Server and the way back again.

We are currently looking on how to evolve this to a more robust solution with less transfer objects in between while maintaining security as the web interface has login credentials.

Ideally we would replace all with SignalR as this would make the client side also easier; we have a lot of TypeScript currently to do Rx calls.

My particular concern would be security in having SignalR directly to the Windows Service.

Comment: This is incredibly broad and there are likely several questions here.

Comment: I would be more specifically looking what the best approach is to exchange data between  the webserver and windows service in a bi-directional method.